# Проблема с кодировкой (название сервера)

Tags: java, android, utf-8, cp1251

Столкнулся с проблемой - с сервера (SAMP) приходит название сервера, но в неизвестно какой кодировке. Текст должен быть: RUSSIAN STATE | ТЕСТОВЫЙ. Вот в кодировке utf8:
[image: utf8]

А по факту, как видим неизвестные символы. А вот когда я попытался перевести в кодировку windows 1251:
[image: cp1251]

Как мы знаем, по умолчанию в android используется utf8. (ромб с вопросительным знаком). Но я попытался задать кодировку 1251, используя getBytes: [image: getBytes]

[image: код]

В итоге мне не помогло. Что делать, не знаю, не особо разбираюсь в кодировках. Но заранее скажу, на стороне сервера все нормально, так как обычный ПК клиент SAMP отображает название корректно.[image: SAMP]

Comment: Ну попробуйте ascii или 866, только так. Сама строка не говорит о том, в какой она кодировке

Comment: пробовал, не помогает

Comment: Попробуйте `String hostname = new String(hostnameBA, Charset.forName("windows-1251"))`

Comment: я еще вчера так и исправил эту проблему)